# How to resize collada models to a given size

Tags: three.js

I will resite a collada model to a user given size...

Maybe with patterns, maybe with scalling only.

My actual idea is to implement a bounding box with the given sizes. And then scale the collada until it hits one side of the bounding box.

But maybe there are better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You want to resize a model to a given size. The model may have child meshes.

One solution is to determine the model's bounding box.

```
var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );

var boxCenter = box.center();

var boxSize = box.size();
```

Then, depending on your criteria, you can reset the model's scale and position:

```
model.position.set( x, y, z );

model.scale.set( s, s, s ); // same value for each component to prevent distortion
```

How you determine the new position and scale is up to you.

three.js r.71

Comment: you mean i should scale in little steps and after every step I should check the boxSize. And when I hit the requirements I should determine?

Comment: No, you solve the math equation directly for the proper scale based on the conditions you specify. That is a math question, and not a collada or three.js question. If you have a specific math problem you cannot solve, then post the problem on a math site.